# hide ip address

Tags: c#, ip

I'm using HTTPWebrequest to get data from a website. Is there any way I can hide my IP or generate new ones? It doesn't have to be done trough code, a software would also be ok.

PS: I'm not doing anything illegal, it is a project I have for university

Comment: It's always questionable when you are trying to hide an IP.  Are you using a website that only allows so many requests per IP or something?

Comment: @BuildStarted if he is doing anything bad he should at least use 7 of them ;)

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain - hehe - yeah, whenever I see "it's not for illegal purposes" or something similar...that's usually what it's for :)

Comment: If you want to literally regenerate your IP address on the net, you can unplug your modem then replug it. With most home Internet connection, this will give you a new IP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your only answer would be using a proxy, you can find web proxies, or you can download ones that will work on your computer. This will change the IP address that the server will see.

Comment: `This will change your IP address`, it should be `This will change the IP address that the server will see`. You're IP doesn't actually change, it's that since you are using a proxy, the server thinks the one who is speaking with is the proxy not you.

Comment: @HoLYVieR You are correct, I answered that in a way that someone needed to know what proxies were already.